# Streaming data for a realtime web application

Tags: html, spring-boot, streaming, spring-websocket, java-websocket

I am building a web application where i need to push continuous data from server to client for a specific interval with one time request from client. 
Its the Same as in trading application where user's login the application once and post that he is able to see the rates changing continuously without making any further requests.

While researching i found out, by polling we can achieve this but at the same time it is also an overhead on the number of connections.

My server is a micro-service model and client is HTML5.

Suggestions and help will be appreciated.

Comment: You can use the WebSockets API for server push.

Comment: whats your framework at server side ?

Comment: Using spring-boot in server side. 
Also i have tried to make a WebSockets, but i can't get read of this exception : "Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection?"

I know its because of http and https connection, but an explained and solvable solution will be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have added my code for the same :
server code : http://www.browxy.com/SavedCode/149334
client code : http://www.browxy.com/SavedCode/149335

exception :   The HTTP request to initiate the WebSocket connection failed
Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection?

Comment: Update : i am able to remove the SSL message error , but still getting this error while creating the session and unable to find any solution : The HTTP response from the server [404] did not permit the HTTP upgrade to WebSocket

Comment: i got the solution, i was directly launching the html page instead of launching it from the server.

Comment: You can use websockets to continously push data from backend to frontend. The frontend and backend exchange message on particular topic. Whenever backend has some data to publish, it will send message on the common topic and it will be immediately displayed on UI. You need to establish connection just once and data will keep flowing. I did this using spring boot as backend and angular as frontend. The backend continuously receives messages from kafka and sends message to angular frontend. Its like a live dashboard which keeps displaying data as and when it happens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Server Sent Events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Server-sent_events/Using_server-sent_events). It works exactly as you need it. The client connects one time and then the server send an event (i.e. an object serialized to JSON) every time something changes in the backend by registering a `callback function` to be called every time an event is received.

Below is a sample data flow:

```
event: userconnect
data: {"username": "bobby", "time": "02:33:48"}

event: usermessage
data: {"username": "bobby", "time": "02:34:11", "text": "Hi everyone."}

event: userdisconnect
data: {"username": "bobby", "time": "02:34:23"}

event: usermessage
data: {"username": "sean", "time": "02:34:36", "text": "Bye, bobby."}
```

[Here](https://spring.io/blog/2017/03/08/spring-tips-server-sent-events-sse) is a tutorial for Spring.

Comment: Hi Consntantin, appreciate for your time and help but i am using spring-boot framework for the server-side code.

Comment: @gauravkumar so? It can be done with any server side technology that can keep a connection open. I've done it in PHP and JavaScript/Node.js.

Comment: @gauravkumar take a look at https://spring.io/blog/2017/03/08/spring-tips-server-sent-events-sse

Comment: ohh thanks !!, will try to implement and if will got any issue(hope not), will comeback.

Comment: @gauravkumar You are welcome. Also, mark the answer as solution if this is the case; thanks

Comment: yeah sure, let me implement this first and check whether i will achieve what i am expecting or else will continue the discussion to improve the same.

Comment: Hi Constantin, First of all thanks for your effort and time for the solution.
I am successfully able to implement the SSE for my application and able to achieve as well, but the only problem i got with it is that(or might be i couldn't find) there is no way that i can handle the exception if the client automatically closes or the server stops.
While in the WS, there are inbuild functionality where if anyone of the side goes down we can handle those in the close-connection methods.

Comment: @gauravkumar in Java?

Comment: @gauravkumar I think you should create a new question about this issue